# Как анимировать добавление элемента в DOM? ( анимация при расширении )

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть основная таблица навезем ее **таблица1**, в которую я вставляю строки через append. В эти строки я добавляю **таблицу2** которая шире чем исходная. В результате **таблица1** естественно расширяется по границам **таблицы2**

Вопрос:
Как анимировать расширение **таблицы1**?

*Возможно кто то может подумать, что этот вопрос решен [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/108775/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-dom) но там решения моей проблемы нет.*

Comment: А что `transition` не справляется?

Comment: Он по видимому не может реагировать на несанкционированные вмешательства в DOM

Comment: Анимируйте тогда таблицу2, и вместе с ней будет анимироваться таблица1.

Comment: Попробовал так: transition: all 1000ms;                                                                                  Все ровно когда таблица2 добавляется в новую строку-контейнер, эта строка контейнер резко расширяется вниз без анимации  под размер  таблицы2

Comment: Так Вы таблицу2 добавляет готовую, с заданными параметрами ширины и т.д. Вы же ее не анимируете - при обычной вставке, просто нечему анимтроваться